# eval form supposed to evaluate a given form in a null lexical environment, I don't get what I expect

Tags: common-lisp

Let's say I have a special var:

```
(defvar x 20)
```

then I do the following:

```
(let ((x 1)) (eval '(+ x 1))
```

which evaluates to 2.

According to CLHS, eval "Evaluates form in the current dynamic environment and the null lexical environment". So, I would expect to get 21 instead of 2.

Am I missing something?

Now if I have no dynamic binding for symbol y, evaluating

```
(let ((y 1)) (eval '(+ y 1))
```

I get condition: "The variable Y is unbound", which makes sense, since there is no dynamic binding for y.

Note: I'm using SBCL 1.0.57

Appreciate your help in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

in your example `x` is `special` which means it is bound in the *dynamic environment*

`y` is *not* special, so it is bound in the *lexical environment*

---

so at the time of the first `eval` the environments could be represented like this:

```
dynamic environment:  { x : 1 } -> { x : 20, ...other global variables... } -> nil
lexical environment:  nil
```

the symbol `x` is special so `eval` looks up `x` in the *current* dynamic 
environment and finds `x = 1`

---

assuming it was run in same lisp as the last example, the environment of your second `eval` looks like this:

```
dynamic environment: { x : 20,  ...other global variables... } -> nil
lexical environment: { y :  1 } -> nil
```

the symbol `y` is *not* special so `eval` looks up `y` in the *null* 
lexical environment -- *not* the current lexical environment -- and finds nothing.

this makes sense when you realize that lisp is usually compiled, and the lexical
environment can be optimized down to simple `mov` instructions in some cases.

Comment: This helps a lot! I appreciate your help very much!

Answer (score 6):

`DEFVAR` declares its variables special. Globally, everywhere. You can also not remove this easily.

That's also the reason you should never use common names like `x`, `i`, `list` as variable names for `DEFVAR`. Make sure that you use `*x*`, `*i*` and `*list*` instead. Otherwise all variables, even local ones, with these common names are declared special.

Comment: Yes, using earmuffs with special variables is the best practice  supported by everybody (me including, as it makes code clearer), but not the author of "Let Over Lambda" book to point out the duality of syntax. In this particular case I wanted to see which binding would be picked up by eval. From what I understand since X is special, let will change existing "global" binding of X to the one specified by let form, and that's why eval picks up value of 1 newly bound by let. Please correct me if I understood it wrong.

Comment: @Svarog: LET does not change the global binding. It creates a new local binding. In this case a dynamic binding. Since the X in the code to be evaluated is automatically a special variable (the DEFVAR declaration has effect), EVAL uses the local dynamic binding.